# Converting from one String reprensation of a Date to another in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, date-conversion, converters

In my application, I have to deal with a Date that comes as a String, formatted as **yyyy-MM-dd**. I can't change the underlying class.
On the view, for user convenience I want it to be displayed in **dd.MM.yyyy** format.

From what I understand, f:convertDateTime> only works on java.util.Date, not on Strings that just pretend to be Dates. So I wrote my own converter:

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date tempDate = inputFormat.parse((String) value);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        return outputFormat.format(tempDate);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works, but it just feels wrong. Converting from a String to a date and back to a different String. Also, I like how convertDateTime deals with timezones and user locale which is completely ignored in this approach.

Is there a better solution? Like parsing a date and then passing it through f:convertDateTime?

Comment: I took a stab at it. :P

Answer (score 2):

Back end (Bean):

```
String string = "2014-05-14";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sat May 14 00:00:00 BOT 2014
setDate(date); //Set date in bean
```

Front end (Reference that field in bean within value):

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" timeZone="EST" type="date" />
</h:outputText>
```

Haven't tested it or anything... Is that kinda what you are looking for?

[Documentation](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html)